# function not having same value at every point

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : (−1,1) \to\Bbb R$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f''(0) > 0$. Show that there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $f(\frac 1n)$ is not equals $1$.

I know that  $f$ has a minima at $0$ and $f'(0)$ is $0$ but how to proceed from here?

Comment: Hint: Consider the sequence $(1/n)$ and $(f(1/n))$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes but why is f (0) not 1 I don't underztand

Comment: Why does $f$ have a minima at 0? (Presumably you mean minimiser?)

Comment: f"(0) is positive so f has a local minima at 0

Comment: @DebarghyaMukherjee: $x \mapsto (x-1)^2$ has a positive second derivative everywhere but does not have a local minimum at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of derivative you get $f'(0)=0$. Since $f''(0) >0$ there exits $\delta >0$ such that $f'(x)>f'(0)=0$ for $0<x<\delta$. This makes $f$ strictly increasing in $(0,\delta)$ making $f(\frac 1 {n+1}) <f(\frac 1 n)$ or $1<1$!

Comment: Sir how can $f'(0)=0$. I guess given $f''(0)>0\implies\displaystyle \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f'(0+h)-f'(0)}{h}>0\implies f'(0+h)>f'(0)$. Am I missing something here?

Comment: $f'(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {f(\frac 1 n) -f(0)} {\frac 1 n-0}$ By continuity $f(0)=1$ so numerator is $0$ for each $n$.

Comment: I get it now Sir. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assume that

$\forall n \in \Bbb N, \; f \left ( \dfrac{1}{n} \right ) = 1; \tag 1$

then by continuity,

$f(0) = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f \left ( \dfrac{1}{n} \right ) = 1; \tag 2$

also,

$f'(0) = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f(1/n) - 1}{1/n} = 0; \tag 3$

since

$f''(0) > 0, \tag 4$

we find that $f(x)$ has a local minimum of value $f(0) = 1$ at $0$; now I claim that there is a fixed $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f'(\alpha) > 0$ for every $\alpha \in (0, \epsilon)$; otherwise, we could find sequences $\epsilon_n \to 0$ and $\alpha_n \in (0, \epsilon_n)$ with $f'(\alpha_n) \le 0$, and then

$f''(0) =  \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f'(\alpha_n) - f'(0)}{\alpha_n} = \lim_{\alpha_n \to \infty} \dfrac{f'(\alpha_n)}{\alpha_n} \le 0 \Rightarrow \Leftarrow f''(0) > 0; \tag 5$

now since $f'(x)$ is differentiable, it is also continuous and thus we may apply the mean value theorem to any $\beta \in (0, \epsilon)$ and obtain

$f(\beta) - 1 = f(\beta) - f(0) = f'(\gamma) (\beta - 0) = f'(\gamma) \beta, \; \gamma \in (0, \beta); \tag 6$

since $f'(\gamma) > 0$ this yields

$f(\beta) = 1 + f'(\gamma) \beta; \tag 7$

we see that every $\beta \in (0, \epsilon)$ satisfies

$f(\beta) > 1, \tag 8$

but this contradicts our assumption (1), and thus

$\exists n \in \Bbb N, \; f \left ( \dfrac{1}{n} \right ) \ne 1. \tag 9$

Note that we have in fact proved that $n$ in (9) may be taken arbitrarily large, and thus there are an infinite number of such $n$, which also follows from (7)-(8).  In fact, we have proved the stronger statement than (1),

$\exists M \in \Bbb N, \; n > M \Longrightarrow  f \left ( \dfrac{1}{n} \right ) \ne 1. \tag{10}$